# Conditional probability (urns and balls)

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

From an urn, containing 6 white and 12 black balls, one takes balls randomly one by one until the second white ball appears. 
What is the probability that:
1) second white ball appears on the second step
2) second white ball appears on the third step
3) second white ball appears on the k-th step

My solution is the following.
The probability of the second white ball is
$$Pr(X=2)=\frac{6}{18}\frac{5}{17}$$

The probability of the third white ball is
$$Pr(X=3)=\frac{6}{18}\frac{12}{17}\frac{5}{16}+ \frac{12}{18}\frac{6}{17}\frac{5}{16} = \frac{2⋅6⋅5⋅12}{18⋅17⋅16} $$

Therefore, the probability
$$Pr(X=k)=\frac{(k-1)⋅6⋅5⋅(18-k)!⋅12!}{18!⋅(12-k+2)!}$$

Could somebody, please, check my solution, especially the third part. Thank you.

Comment: In the $\Pr(x = 3)$ case, you meant to say the probability that the second white ball is selected on the third draw.

Comment: Yes, the calculation looks fine to me.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The first white ball can be selected either on the first or second draw and the second white ball is selected on the third draw. Thus, Pr(x=3). X is the random variable showing the number of the step on which the second white ball is selected.

Comment: @Makhayama Any further questions?

Answer (score 1):

I used the hypergeometric distribution for the $(k-1)$-th draw.

The probability to draw one white ball and $k-2$ black balls in $k-1$ drawings is

$$\frac{\binom{6}{1}\cdot \binom{12}{k-2}}{\binom{18}{k-1}}=\frac{6\cdot 12!\cdot (k-1)!\cdot (19-k)!}{18!\cdot (k-2)!\cdot (14-k)!}=\frac{6\cdot 12!\cdot (k-1)\cdot (19-k)!}{18!\cdot (14-k)!}$$

At the k-th draw we have to pick a white ball. The probability is $\frac{5}{19-k}$. In total I get

$$P(X=k)=\frac{5\cdot 6\cdot 12!\cdot (k-1)\cdot (18-k)!}{18!\cdot (14-k)!}$$

This is the same result you got.

Comment: Alternatively you seek the probability that the six white balls are distibuted one into the first $k−1$ places, one into the next place, and four into the remaining $18−k$places. Same result: $$\mathsf P(X=k)=\dfrac{\dbinom{k−1}1\dbinom11\dbinom{18−k}4}{\dbinom{18}6}=\dfrac{6!~(k−1)~12!~(18−k)!}{4!~18!~(14−k)!}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp An elegant alternative approach.